# MySQL table, what is INDEX?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I know PRIMARY key is to have unique value, what about INDEX? What is the function of a table column with INDEX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

INDEX columns are exactly that. They're indexed to make it faster to look up information using that column. MySQL typically stores Indexes in B-Trees or R-Trees. An appropriate case for the use of an index would be if you're using a where clause on a particular column (or group of columns) regularly.

Indexes are a topic worthy of whole chapters in database books, a good place to start looking for more information might be the [mysql reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: It might be appropriate to point out that "faster" in this context can mean "a hell of a lot faster."

Comment: And by 'a hell of a lot faster' can often mean a hundred or a thousand or even a million times faster. Seriously!

Comment: If my data is not very huge, should I still use index??

Comment: Yes, with indexes selects will be a lot faster. In order to find an item using index database will not read all data. It'll just look in index and read the item you need.

Answer (score 5):

An INDEX in MySQL, performs the same kind of function an INDEX does at the end of a book. It enables faster lookup for your information when you do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM MY-DB-WITH-INDEXES> WHERE <INDEX_FIELD=foo_bar>
```

Good choice of the columns used to form an index always makes a good database design.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [this good description of indexes in databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database))